# Google Search Appliance - Can I export the 'Last Modified' HTTP Header from indexed documents?

Tags: http, header, google-search-appliance

I am trying to get the 'Last Modified' header from every page indexed by our Google Search Appliance box. I can export indexed pages but it does not include the 'Last Modified' field. My experience with this is very limited, can anybody offer assistance?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Export URLs" feature of GSA to extract some information along with the URLs but I don't think you can get 'Last Modified' date directly. 
Please check [this](https://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/72/admin_console_help/status_export_urls.html) GSA documentation for export urls feature.
As per GSA documentation on "[Determining Document Changes with If-Modified-Since Headers and the Content Checksum](http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/70/gsa_doc_set/admin_crawl/introduction.html#1076363)" GSA will not modifiy content if the document is not updated but not sure how it will treat the crawl date of the document. If GSA doesn't change crawl date when document is not modified, you can use the "last_crawled" attribute of "Export urls" log to know "Last Modified " date of the document.

Regards,
Mohan

Answer (score 0):

You can use the administrative API for that task.

http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/72/gsa_doc_set/acapi_protocol/acapi_protocol.html#1109492